# Minecraft - how can you teleport someone in an area to another area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm asking if there is a 3x3 area and if a player hits a specific part of that area can he[image] be teleported to a similar 3x3 area I set up?

Comment: Sure you can, just use the teleporting command. But what are your restrictions? I assume there's more to this, otherwise you wouldn't ask.

Comment: Are you new to the teleporting command? There's lots of resources for you out there, but for the record the synax is /tp <target> <destination> . "target" can be @a, @p, @e, @s or @r (look inside a command block and see what they do). Then you have three coordinates after that, either set coordinates or by what'stheirface ~ ~ ~. The first ~ is X, the second is Y and the third is Z. Hit F3 and you'll see a little section saying "Block:" and then some numbers. Those are your coordinates. You can then use execute to detect when a player is standing on a block, then combine it with the tp command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are sub-components for commands. for instance: /kill @e[type=!minecraft:player].

the command you're looking for is /tp @a[radius=2] (coordinates of another platform)

just set the command block to "repeat" and "always active" and be on your way!!

note that the command block will have to be placed as that middle block. alternatively, extend the radius to 3 or 4.